# Sort by specific date? numbers? included list in list

Tags: python, list, sorting, replace, flatten

I am doing some works for studying, and stuck in some problems!

I have this schedule lists

```
lists = [['Lunch', '2021-04-05 12:00', '2021-04-05 13:00'], ['Dinner', '2021-04-05 13:00', '2021-04-05 14:00'], ['Lunch', '2021-04-04 13:00', '2021-04-04 14:00']]
```

And, I would like to sort this list by start date which is lists[1]

What I tried to do is below

```
lists = [['Lunch', '2021-04-05 12:00', '2021-04-05 13:00'], ['Dinner', '2021-04-05 13:00', '2021-04-05 14:00'], ['감자', '2021-04-04 13:00', '2021-04-04 14:00']]
sorted_lists = []
for i in lists:
    i[1] = i[1].replace('-', '').replace(' ', '').replace(':', '')
    i[2] = i[1].replace('-', '').replace(' ', '').replace(':', '')
    sorted_lists.append(i)
    
sorted(sorted_lists, key=lambda date: date[1])

print(sorted_lists)
```

**Note, I don't want to use any module such as date, time**

But, it switch the location of each items.

Is there any best way to sort by start date?

Thank you.

If my explanation is bad, please let me know..!

Thank you guys for reading

Comment: `sorted()` returns a _new_ sorted list; it does not update the original list.  Use `sorted_lists.sort(key=...)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dates are as you show (i.e., their lexical order is consistent with the time order), then why not simply:

```py
sorted(lists, key=lambda e: e[1])
```

For the data you gave, that gives:

```py
[['Lunch', '2021-04-04 13:00', '2021-04-04 14:00'],
 ['Lunch', '2021-04-05 12:00', '2021-04-05 13:00'],
 ['Dinner', '2021-04-05 13:00', '2021-04-05 14:00']]
```

Clarification: I always try to avoid side-effects in my answers. That means that the code I provide usually creates new values and doesn't affect existing variables, unless duly noted. I consider these side-effects to be potentially dangerous, unless very clearly documented. Imagine a function that you call sneakily modifying your lists or your DataFrame in-place...

As such, the answer above should be assigned to a result variable of choice. I see you use `sorted_lists`, so:

```py
sorted_lists = sorted(lists, key=lambda e: e[1])
```

Comment: `sorted()` returns a new list; it does not sort in-place.

Comment: @JohnGordon, who said anything about sorting in-place?

Comment: Give me this [['Lunch', '2021-04-05 12:00', '2021-04-05 13:00'], ['Dinner', '2021-04-05 13:00', '2021-04-05 14:00'], ['Lunch', '2021-04-04 13:00', '2021-04-04 14:00']]

Comment: of course, the example I gave is producing a new list, not sorting the original in-place (which would be a sin)... Just assign this to your desired output variable.

Comment: @PierreD Let me try again!